# Integrating paypal payment gateway to website and accept payment from USA

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

Hi everyone I have a personal website and i provide service to USA peoples through my personal website. Now I want to integrate a paypal checout button to my website so any one can transfer payment into my paypal account. Is it possible that the website can accept payment through credit card if not what then i have to do.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that paypal has their own method to doing this on their website. If you configure this the right way (on their site), they should give you a link to where people could pay you. Then ofc all you have to do is add a button to your site that links to that url.